# How to get absolute path to "outputs" folder in Azure ML

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-save-write-experiment-files) of Azure Machine Learning, under "Where to write files", it says

> Otherwise, write files to the `./outputs` and/or `./logs` folder.

These are relative paths, i.e. relative to the folder where my script is run by the Azure ML framework. I was not able to find a function in the Azure ML SDK that would return the absolute path -- have I missed it or is there none? (Meaning that I should read the `cwd` at the beginning of my script and store it myself.)

Answer (score 1):

For **absolute path** refer this code block:

```
processed_output_data = PipelineData("processed_data1",datastore=def_blob_store)
print("PipelineData object created")

train_data = PythonScriptStep(
    script_name="sample.py", 
    arguments=["--input_data", blob_input_data, "--output_train", processed_output_data],
    inputs=[blob_input_data],
    outputs=[processed_output_data],
    compute_target=aml_compute, 
    source_directory=source_directory,
    runconfig=run_config
)
```

for information **refer** this Github [link](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-with-data-dependency-steps.ipynb).